# IIS UrlRewrite RegEx differences with .NET RegEx

Tags: asp.net, regex, iis, url-rewriting

I have a valid RegEx pattern in .NET:

`(?>.*param1=value1.*)(?<!.*param2=\d+.*)` which matches if:

- query string contains `param1=value1`
- but *does not* contain `param2=` a number

It works in .NET. However IIS URLRewrite complains that it is not a valid pattern.

Can I not use zero-width negative look behind `(?<!   )` expressions with IIS URLRewrite?

Note that I tried to apply this pattern both in web.config (properly changing `<` and `>` to `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively, as well as in the IIS Manager - all without success.

Comment: Can't you simplify it as `^(?!.*param2=\d).*param1=value1`? Or if you need to match the whole string, add trailing `.*`: `^(?!.*param2=\d).*param1=value1.*`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! This works! However the question remains as to the differences. I thought that the 2 RegEx engines used are equivalent.

Comment: No, as you can see the syntaxes differ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS URLRewrite default regex syntax is **ECMAScript**, that is not compatible with .NET regex syntax. See [*URL Rewrite Module Configuration Reference*](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference):

> `ECMAScript` – Perl compatible ([ECMAScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) standard compliant) regular expression  syntax. This is a default option for any rule.

You cannot use a lookbehind at all, you will have to rely on lookaheads only:

```
^(?!.*param2=\d).*param1=value1.*
```

**Pattern explanation**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*param2=\d)` - if there is `param2=` followed with a digit (`\d`) after 0+ characters other than a newline fails the match (return no match)
- `.*param1=value1.*` - match a whole line that contains `param1=value1`

You can enhance this rule by adding `\b` around `param1=value1` to only match it as a whole word.