# IIS Url Rewite: Add Trailing Slash, Preserve Anchors and Query Strings

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I've searched several SO posts and haven't found what I'm looking for. It might exists but might be fairly old enough to not show up for me. I found a post ([Nginx rewrite: add trailing slash, preserve anchors and query strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46420985/nginx-rewrite-add-trailing-slash-preserve-anchors-and-query-strings)) so close to what I need, but it's regex solution does not work for URL Rewrite for IIS, unless I'm doing it wrong.

**Problem**

I'm trying to add a forward slash `/` to the end of my url paths while also preserving any existing for query strings `?` and anchors `#`.

**Desired Solution**

Basically, here's the desired results to each problem:

```
Entry: https://my.site.com/about
Result: https://my.site.com/about/

Entry: https://my.site.com/about?query=string
Result: https://my.site.com/about/?query=string

Entry: https://my.site.com/about#TestAnchor
Result: https://my.site.com/about/#TestAnchor

Entry: https://my.site.com/about?query=string#TestAnchor
Result: https://my.site.com/about/?query=string#TestAnchor
```

**Current Tests**

Our current regex ignores query strings and anchors, but I would like to take them into consideration now.

```
<rule name="AddTrailingSlash" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^([^.?]+[^.?/])$" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

I've also tested another regex but it only works if the url contains both a query string AND an anchor.

```
<rule name="AddTrailingSlash" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(.*)(\?.*?)(\#.*?)$" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/{R:2}{R:3}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

**NOTE:** I just tested this last one (`^(.*)(\?.*?)(\#.*?)$`) and it actually doesn't work. If the url already contains a `/` before the `?` the test passes which it should not, so I have more work to do here.

**Question**

Is there a single regex that I can use to solve this or do I need to use multiple rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

###### IIS Rewrite (ALL) URIs with `Trailing Slash` & preserve [`Fragment`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment) and [`Query Strings`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)

```
<rule name="AddTrailingSlash" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^([^/]+:\/\/[^/#?]+|[^?#]+?)\/?((?:[^/?#]+\.[^/?#]+)?(?:[?#].*)?$)" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/{R:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

[**IIS** use **ECMAScript**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38451836/7514010) so you can **Try it** here : **https://regexr.com/6ele7**

---

##### Update

###### IIS Rewrite (Considered) URIs with `Trailing Slash` & preserve [`Fragment`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment) and [`Query Strings`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)

```
<rule name="AddTrailingSlash" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^([^/]+:\/\/[^/#?]+|[^?#]+\/[^/.?#]+)([?#].*)?$" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/{R:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

**Try it** here : **https://regexr.com/6fk3g**

---

```lisp
http://127.0.0.1  -->  http://127.0.0.1/
https://localhost  -->  https://localhost/
https://localhost?  -->  https://localhost/?
https://localhost/  -->  https://localhost/
https://my.site.com  -->  https://my.site.com/
https://my.site.com:443?  -->  https://my.site.com:443/?
https://my.site.com/  -->  https://my.site.com/
https://my.site.com/about.php  -->  https://my.site.com/about.php
https://my.site.com/about.php?  -->  https://my.site.com/about.php?
https://my.site.com/about  -->  https://my.site.com/about/
https://my.site.com/about?  -->  https://my.site.com/about/?
https://my.site.com/about/  -->  https://my.site.com/about/
https://my.site.com/about/?  -->  https://my.site.com/about/?
https://my.site.com/about?query  -->  https://my.site.com/about/?query
https://my.site.com/about/?query  -->  https://my.site.com/about/?query
https://my.site.com/about.php?query  -->  https://my.site.com/about.php?query
https://my.site.com/about#hash  -->  https://my.site.com/about/#hash
https://my.site.com/about/#hash  -->  https://my.site.com/about/#hash
https://my.site.com/about.php#hash  -->  https://my.site.com/about.php#hash
https://my.site.com/about?query#hash  -->  https://my.site.com/about/?query#hash
https://my.site.com/about/?query#hash  -->  https://my.site.com/about/?query#hash
https://my.site.com/folder.name/about?query  -->  https://my.site.com/folder.name/about/?query
https://my.site.com/about?query#hash:http://test.com?q  -->  https://my.site.com/about/?query#hash:http://test.com?q
```

##### Explaination (All)

- **Level 1** - Lets just think about your examples:

```regex
^([^?#]+?)\/?([?#].*)?$
```

**Group #1:** `^` In first, `[^?#]` Any character except `?`/`#`, Go much but lazy `+?` (Stop on first possible, by looking to next)
**Ignore:** `\/?` Then if a `/` exist or not
**Group #2:** `[?#]` = `?`/`#` And `.*` Any much character next to that till `$` End, `(...)?` If exist

It work well. **But** it will deal not right with:

```lisp
https://my.site.com/about.php?query  -->  https://my.site.com/about.php/?query  !!!
```

So let's add an exception...

- **Level 2** - How if we take possible file name `Name.name.name.ext` as **Group #2**?

```regex
^([^?#]+?)\/?((?:[^/?#]+\.[^/?#]+)?(?:[?#].*)?)$
```

`(?:...)` Non-Capturing group
`([^/?#]+\.[^/?#]+)?` Look for any possible file name or `(?:[?#].*)?` Any possible query or anchor strings

Now everything is OK, except this:

```lisp
https://my.site.com?  -->  https://my.site.com?  !!!
```

So we need another exception in **Group #1**

- **Level 3** - Take just domain URI as an alternative

```regex
^([^/]+:\/\/[^/#?]+|[^?#]+?)\/?((?:[^/?#]+\.[^/?#]+)?(?:[?#].*)?$)
```

`(...|...)` Alternative
`[^/]+:\/\/[^/#?]+` First check if (not lazy) any pattern like `...://...` till not `/ # ?` exist?

Now it work great!

---

##### + Explaination (Considered)

- **Level 4** - How if we just add a Not-Accepting `.` & `/` character set in first group to just match considered URIs and ignore others?

```regex
^([^/]+:\/\/[^/#?]+|[^?#]+\/[^/.?#]+)([?#].*)?$
```

`\/[^/.?#]+` Check if after last `/` the set of characters be not `/.?#`

Now it is even smaller and faster!

---

##### Analyzing other method

As [@károly-szabó](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6804632/) answered well [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70937979/7514010), instead of looking for Not-Accepted character sets, we can look for matched pattern.
So if we want to use the method but in simpler way (2 Groups) (+ Some minor optimization), the regex will be:

```regex
^(https?:\/\/[\w.:-]+\/?(?:[\w.-]+\/)*[\w-]+(?!\/))([?#].*)?$
```

**But** [URI path](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.3) [Accepted characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4669755/7514010) are more.

So a wider version of that Regex can be:

```regex
^(https?:\/\/[\w.:-]+\/?(?:[\w!#-)+-.;=@~]+\/)*[\w!#-);=@~+,-]+(?!\/))([?#].*)?$
```

Try it here: https://regexr.com/6elea

Note: Still "[multibyte Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name#:%7E:text=by%20computers%20in-,multibyte%20Unicode,-.%20Internationalized%20domain%20names) as domain name is allowed" but i ignored that in this method.

---

#### P.S.

Actually i don't think that we should rewrite it on IIS, because of these reasons:

- Anchors char `#` can be part of a folder name (by `%23`)
- A file name can have no extension
- IIS/Browsers usually will (/should) handle Anchors/Queries
  Ref:

  - [IIS: UrlRewrite middleware query strings are preserved](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/5.0/iis-urlrewrite-middleware-query-strings-are-preserved)
  - [Google/Anchor tags are stripped from URLs](https://github.com/google/physical-web/issues/556)
  - [RFC URI References](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt#:%7E:text=are%20reserved.%0A%0A4.-,URI%20References,-The%20term%20%22URI)
  - [URI Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax)
  - [How does IIS URL Rewrite handle # anchor tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19400135/7514010)

I Mean:

```lisp
https://my.site.com/  -->  (=Call root)
https://my.site.com/about  -->  (=Call root > Folder/File name about) 
https://my.site.com/about/  -->  (=Call root > Folder name about) 
https://my.site.com/about?query  -->  (=Call root > Folder/File name about + Query)
https://my.site.com/about/?query  -->  (=Call root > Folder name about + Query)
https://my.site.com/about.php?query  -->  (=Call root > File name about.php + Query)
[When browser strip it:]
https://my.site.com/about#hash  -->  (=Call root > Folder/File name about + Anchor)
https://my.site.com/about/#hash  -->  (=Call root > Folder name about + Anchor)
https://my.site.com/about.php#hash  -->  (=Call root > File name about.php + Anchor)

[If not?]
https://my.site.com/folder#name/?query#hash
https://my.site.com/folder.name/about.php?query=one/two
```

Comment: This looks great and I love the extended explanations, caveats and links to resources. However, it seems to match every url. I'd like for it to not match any urls that are already properly formatted. @károly-szabó does that, but seems to not allow a dash in the url, so I'm looking to use that one if fixed.

Comment: @RoLYroLLs thanks, that idea made the regex more simple, i updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update and sorry for the delay as I was out of town. Now something is not right. I seems to not match one of the lines properly, as if it's matching 2 lines in one. https://imgur.com/a/MiMTLX6

Comment: @RoLYroLLs Nothing is wrong. Actually in URIs you will never have a multi-line input, i use the multi-line sample to you can see examples next to each other, just for view. I could avoid of next-line characters by adding `\n`  in the negative groups (``^([^/]+:\/\/[^/#?\n]+|[^?#\n]+\/[^/.?#\n]+)([?#].*)?$``), but i prefer handle the view by rearrange the examples next to each other to do not make the regex dirty by temporary `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this regex https://regex101.com/r/6TSqaP/2. This is matching every provided example and solves the problem if the url already has an ending `'/'`.

```
^((?:https?:\/\/[\w\.\-]*)(?:[\w\-]+\/)*(?:[\w\-]+)(?!\/))(\?.*?)?(\#.*?)?$
```

I used your second example as base for my regex, with the following logic.
The parts of the url: `scheme://authority/path?query#fragment`

1. first capture group matches the `scheme://authority/path` part of the url
2. second capture group optional and matching the `?query`
3. third capture group also optional and for the `#fragment`

regex explanation

```
^(                            # should start with this
    (?:https?:\/\/[\w\.\-]*)  # match the http or https protocol and the domain
    (?:[\w\-]+\/)*            # match the path except the last element of it (optional)
    (?:[\w\-]+)(?!\/)         # match the last path element, but only if it's not closed with '/'
)                             # {R:1}
(\?.*?)?                      # {R:2} query (optional)
(\#.*?)?                      # {R:3} fragment (optional)
$                             # string should end
```

Nginx

```
<rule name="AddTrailingSlash" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^((?:https?:\/\/[\w\.\-]*)(?:[\w\-]+\/)*(?:[\w\-]+)(?!\/))(\?.*?)?(\#.*?)?$" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/{R:2}{R:3}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Edit: Updated regex to handle dashes (-) and multiple path elements

Comment: After several tests this looks like a great answer, but I need a little help. Our domain name contains a dash `-` in it. Can you help update the regex to allow the domain name to contain dashes? Thank you.

Comment: I assume it would be this `^((?:https?:\/\/[\w\-\.]*)(?:\w+\/)?(?:\w+)(?!\/))(\?.*?)?(\#.*?)?$` (added `\-` near the beginning)

Comment: I've also noticed this does not capture url's with more dashes, ie: `https://my.site.com/about-us` is not captured.

Comment: Last comment: I also noticed this does not capture: `https://my.site.com/about/us`

Comment: I updated my post with a new regex and new link, which matched those cases correctly.

Comment: This method is nice, i used this to improve my answer. Also i had some problems with some accepted characters or not necessary things in the pattern but comment limitation not allow me to explain here well, so as another method i analyse it in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70941532/7514010).